# Recreating PDF form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a Ruby on Rails app in which I want to take an existing PDF (preformatted with fields) and rewrite the PDF with data from an ActiveRecord object.  (i.e. first name, last name, date of birth, etc).  I'm familiar with Prawn and WickedPDF but I'm not sure that this is supported (taking an existing/formatted PDF document and rewriting it with populated data).

I've done some searching and I can't find much on this as everything points to generating custom templates in Prawn or Wicked.

Does anyone have advice on this or perhaps guidance in the right direction?

Comment: Look into Prawn https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn http://railscasts.com/episodes/153-pdfs-with-prawn

Comment: Thanks I've used prawn extensively but my question pertains to taking an existing PDF and injecting data into it inline.